# Positive Look ahead in Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract some characters or words from a string using regular expressions..

Examples of my string contains "Size: M" or "Size: Medium" and I want to extract "M" and "Medium"

These can be anywhere within a long string so...

I was trying to use the following  but it brings back the colon.

```
:\s\w
```

Result : M

But I just want the size and no the colon, I was looking at positive look ahead but not having any luck still excluding the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a look-behind so the whole regex matches what you want (no need to use matching groups)

```
(?<=Size: )\w+
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=Size: )` means the chars immediately preceding the match must be the literal `"Size: "`, and importantly is non-capturing
- `\w+` means "a word"

Answer (score 0):

You will just want to use a capturing group:

```
Size:\s(\w)
```

And then the letter will be contained in the first capture group. You didn't specify what language you are using, but any decent language will have the concept of capturing groups.